# Breaking single line data to multi-line data

Tags: python, list, split

Working on project where i am given raw log data and need to parse it out to a readable state, know enought with python to break off all the undeed part and just left with raw data that needs to be split and formated, but cant figure out a way to break it apart if they put multiple records on the same line, which does not always happen.

This is the string value i am getting so far.

*190205*12,6000,0000000,12,6000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000*190206*01,2050,0100550,01,4999,0000000,,

I need to break it out apart so that each line starts with the *number* value, but since i can assume there will only be 1 or two of them i cant think of a way to do it, and the number of other comma seperate values after it vary so i cant go by length. this is what i am looking to get to use will further operations with data from the above example.

*190205*12,6000,0000000,12,6000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000

*190206*01,2050,0100550,01,4999,0000000,,

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some of the code you've tried already

Comment: The problem is i dont know where to start, how would break up that big string i posted into two small strings based only on knowing that each segment starts with 6 numbers with * on each side of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt = "*190205*12,6000,0000000,12,6000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000*190206*01,2050,0100550,01,4999,0000000,,"

output = list()
i = 0
x = txt.split("*")
while i < len(x):
    if len(x[i]) == 0:
        i += 1
        continue
    print ("*{0}*{1}".format(x[i],x[i+1]))
    output.append("*{0}*{1}".format(x[i],x[i+1]))
    i += 2
```

- Use split to tokezine the words between *
- Print two constitutive tokens

Comment: That looks promising, how could i instead use it with a list that i write those tokenized data into instead of printing?

Comment: @Xanced add them into a list rather then printing as shown in the code

Comment: Thank you again, should do exactly what i need it to.

Comment: @Xanced if your question is resolved can you please accept the answer so that it concludes :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
([*][0-9]*[*])
```

You can catch the header part with this and then split according to it.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as @mujiga but I though a dict might better for further operations

```
txt = "*190205*12,6000,0000000,12,6000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000*190206*01,2050,0100550,01,4999,0000000,,"


datadict=dict()
i=0
x=txt.split("*")
while i < len(x):
    if len(x[i]) == 0:
        i += 1
        continue
    datadict[x[i]]=x[i+1]
    i += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Ali Nuri Seker's suggestion to use regex, here' a simple one lacking lookarounds (which might actually hurt it in this case)

```
>>> import re

>>> string = '''*190205*12,6000,0000000,12,6000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000*190206*01,2050,0100550,01,4999,0000000,,'''

>>> print(re.sub(r'([\*][0-9,]+[\*]+[0-9,]+)', r'\n\1', string))

#Output 
*190205*12,6000,0000000,12,6000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,2590,0000000,13,7000,0000000,13,7000,0000000   
*190206*01,2050,0100550,01,4999,0000000,,
```